# Jinja2: Looking for a View-Helper

Tags: python, jinja2

I'am new to the Jinja2 template engine. Is there something like the view-helpers from Zend Framework? Can i create simple functions and reuse them all over all my template-files?

Something like this?

```
#somewhere in my python code:
def nice_demo_function(message):
    """"return a simple message"""
    return message
```

So i can to use that:

```
<!-- now in my template-file -->
{%  nice_demo_function('yes, this works great!') %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can expose helper functions to your templates.  You could define them using [macros](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/documentation/templates#macros), and then [import](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/documentation/templates#import) them into templates that use them.  You could add functions to the [globals attribute](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/documentation/api#jinja2.Template.globals) of your Template objects, or pass them to the [render()](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/documentation/api#jinja2.Template.render) method.  You could subclass Template to do the same without having to repeat yourself each time.  If you want to get really fancy, you could look into writing [extensions](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/documentation/extensions#jinja-extensions) as well (but you probably don't need to go that deep).

Answer (score 2):

At some point you will have created a Jinja2 environment. The environment has an attribute on it called filters which is a dict that maps names to functions. So what you want to do is:

```
def my_helper(value):
  return "-~*#--- %s ---#*~-" % value

env = Jinja2.Environment(...)
env.filters['my_helper'] = my_helper
```

Now in your template you can do:

```
<p>The winner is {{ winner | my_helper }}</p>
```

And your function will be called with the value of the variable, in this case `winner`. If you are using Pylons, this all happens in `config/environment.py`.